# Font color of bootstrap nav-tabs not changing in active state

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to change the font color of the bootstrap nav-tab when clicked.
I'm able to change the font color of unselected nav tabs to green by using the css .nav-tabs>li>a, but the css block
nav-tabs>li.active>a does not seem to be functioning for changing color of selected tab. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .nav-tabs>li>a{
  color:green;
  }
  .nav-tabs>li.active>a{
  color:green;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active"
      href="#id1"
      data-toggle="tab">one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#id2"
      class="nav-link"
      data-toggle="tab">two</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not correct. `.active` class is in anchor tag. You have given it in `li`

Change

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a{
  color:green;
  }
```

to

```
.nav-tabs > li > a.active {
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. Helped speed up my homework

Answer (score 0):

for coloring the active state, you have to override the bootstrap styling, like this: `.nav-tabs a.nav-link.active`

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .nav-tabs>li>a{
  color:green;
  }
  .nav-tabs a.nav-link.active {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
<body>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active"
      href="#id1"
      data-toggle="tab">one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="#id2"
      class="nav-link"
      data-toggle="tab">two</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a{
     color:green;
}
```

You can use following code to change the color of selected tab

```
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active{
    color:red; /*color you want*/
}
```